# How can I create random additional rows and append it to an existing data frame?

Tags: r, dataset

Suppose I have the following df:

```
head(df1)
  international_plan voice_mail_plan number_vmail_messages
1                 no             yes                    25
2                 no             yes                    26
3                 no              no                     0
4                yes              no                     0
5                yes              no                     0
6                yes              no                     0
  total_day_minutes total_day_calls total_day_charge total_eve_minutes
1             265.1             110            45.07             197.4
2             161.6             123            27.47             195.5
3             243.4             114            41.38             121.2
4             299.4              71            50.90              61.9
5             166.7             113            28.34             148.3
6             223.4              98            37.98             220.6
  total_eve_calls total_eve_charge total_night_minutes total_night_calls
1              99            16.78               244.7                91
2             103            16.62               254.4               103
3             110            10.30               162.6               104
4              88             5.26               196.9                89
5             122            12.61               186.9               121
6             101            18.75               203.9               118
  total_night_charge total_intl_minutes total_intl_calls total_intl_charge
1              11.01               10.0                3              2.70
2              11.45               13.7                3              3.70
3               7.32               12.2                5              3.29
4               8.86                6.6                7              1.78
5               8.41               10.1                3              2.73
6               9.18                6.3                6              1.70
  number_customer_service_calls churn
1                             1    no
2                             1    no
3                             0    no
4                             2    no
5                             3    no
6                             0    no
```

I am looking to try rsparkling +h2o framework on "largish" data to enhance my understanding on how to tackle biggish data on local machine.

Instead of downloading large data from net, what if I can scale up existing small data so that I do not waste time of preprocessing but concentrate on ML modeling at scale.

What I am looking for is to randomly add data, i.e., rows, only from the existing data (maintaining the same columns) based on, let's say, some distribution for numeric (normal dist) & categorical columns (maintaining the proportion frequency of levels), so that I increase the dimensions, say, from initial 3333 x 17 to, say, 1000000 x 17, using R. This is for testing purposes only.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Expected df:

```
  international_plan voice_mail_plan number_vmail_messages
1                 no             yes                    25
2                 no             yes                    26
3                 no              no                     0
4                yes              no                     0
5                yes              no                     0
6                yes              no                     0
-
1000000          no               yes                    20


  total_day_minutes total_day_calls total_day_charge total_eve_minutes
1             265.1             110            45.07             197.4
2             161.6             123            27.47             195.5
3             243.4             114            41.38             121.2
4             299.4              71            50.90              61.9
5             166.7             113            28.34             148.3
6             223.4              98            37.98             220.6
  total_eve_calls total_eve_charge total_night_minutes total_night_calls
1              99            16.78               244.7                91
2             103            16.62               254.4               103
3             110            10.30               162.6               104
4              88             5.26               196.9                89
5             122            12.61               186.9               121
6             101            18.75               203.9               118
-          
1000000       50             20.22               189.23               100

  total_night_charge total_intl_minutes total_intl_calls total_intl_charge
1              11.01               10.0                3              2.70
2              11.45               13.7                3              3.70
3               7.32               12.2                5              3.29
4               8.86                6.6                7              1.78
5               8.41               10.1                3              2.73
6               9.18                6.3                6              1.70
-          
1000000         10.23               7.33               8              2.52

 number_customer_service_calls churn
1                             1    no
2                             1    no
3                             0    no
4                             2    no
5                             3    no
6                             0    no
-          
1000000                       2    yes
```

Comment: Do you want a base R solution or use specific packages?

Comment: @LAP anything wud do as of now.

Answer (score 1):

A quick function for simple `if` statements will get you the random values, which you could afterwards put together with `cbind.data.frame` and `merge` it to your data.

Example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = factor(c(1,2,1,2,1), 1:2, labels = c("yes", "no")),
                 b = 1:5,
                 c = rnorm(5))

    a b          c
1 yes 1 -0.6264538
2  no 2  0.1836433
3 yes 3 -0.8356286
4  no 4  1.5952808
5 yes 5  0.3295078
```

The function checks for data type and returns `n` randomly generated values using the distribution of the variable:

```
FUN1 <- function(x, n = 1, seed = 1){
  set.seed(seed)
  if(is.character(x)){
    y <- sample(sort(unique(x)), n, replace = T, prob = table(x))
  }
  if(is.factor(x)){
    y <- sample(levels(x), n, replace = T, prob = table(x))
  }
  if(is.integer(x)){
    y <- round(rnorm(n, mean(x), sd(x)))
  }
  if(!is.integer(x) & is.numeric(x)){
    y <- rnorm(n, mean(x), sd(x))
  }
  return(y)
}
```

Loop it over the empirical data with `lapply`:

```
newvalues <- lapply(df, FUN1, n = 10)

$a
 [1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "no"  "no"  "no"  "yes"

$b
 [1] 2 3 2 6 4 2 4 4 4 3

$c
 [1] -0.4727769  0.3057584 -0.6738021  1.6623976  0.4459399 -0.6592326  0.5977084  0.8388290  0.6826185 -0.1642204
```

Now `cbind.data.frame` them with `do.call`:

```
df1 <- do.call("cbind.data.frame", newvalues)

> df1
     a b          c
1  yes 2 -0.4727769
2  yes 3  0.3057584
3  yes 2 -0.6738021
4   no 6  1.6623976
5  yes 4  0.4459399
6   no 2 -0.6592326
7   no 4  0.5977084
8   no 4  0.8388290
9   no 4  0.6826185
10 yes 3 -0.1642204
```

and `merge` them:

```
df2 <- merge(df, df1, all = TRUE)

     a b          c
1  yes 1 -0.6264538
2  yes 2 -0.6738021
3  yes 2 -0.4727769
4  yes 3 -0.8356286
5  yes 3 -0.1642204
6  yes 3  0.3057584
7  yes 4  0.4459399
8  yes 5  0.3295078
9   no 2 -0.6592326
10  no 2  0.1836433
11  no 4  0.5977084
12  no 4  0.6826185
13  no 4  0.8388290
14  no 4  1.5952808
15  no 6  1.6623976
```

---

The process is rather quick with the exception of the `merge`. With really big data, this merge may take some time. A quick test with 10 million new rows of three variables took a fraction of a second for the generation and cbind, but about one minute to merge. Considering that the biggest part of your data would be randomly generated anyway, you could just use only the generated dataset, therefore skipping the merging process altogether.

Comment: awesome solution. This seems an apt example to go for parallelization.

Comment: Is it possible to save the newly created df as rds format rather than data.frame?? (in df_new<-do.call("cbind.data.frame", newvalues))

Comment: Sure, just wrap a `saveRDS()` call around it.

Answer (score 0):

One fast and easy way to preserve proportions, would be to bootstrap (sampling with replacement) from your column vectors/ features.

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) sample(x, 1e6, replace = TRUE)))
```

If you want to simulate from empirical distribution for numerical features, you might need to write a custom function